# Wordpress MAMP Installation Issue

Tags: apache, local-installation

I have MAMP configured in my machine and I've been using it to run multiple Wordpress installs with no issue until this new site where the Wordpress install is in a subdirectory.

The site is installed under htdocs and it has the following structure: /mylocalpath/htdocs/www.mysite.com/Web Applicatin/WordpressInstallCoreFiles

For some reason this keeps returning a 404.  I followed the steps for "[Wordpress in Subdirectory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)" but still no luck.

I do have the hosts file set up correctly for the local domain.

Any tips or ideas on how to get my site running on the subdirectory?  Anything I can do in Apache to configure this correctly?

Comment: Have you tried without the space in the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with my current Apache install. After uninstalling an reinstalling the latest version of Apache, everything worked as expected.